# Previous form not clearing in time for new form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have one form displayed with `ShowDialog()`.  After that form is closed, I show a new form with a progress bar except the previous form doesn't completely get removed before progress bar form appears. How do I handle this?

```
using(FormA formA= new FormA)
{ 
    if(formA.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {

    }
}

FormB formB = new FormB;
formB.Show();
...{
    formB.progressBar.PerformStep();
...}
formB.Close();
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can see

Comment: If you are not using a BackgroundWorker for your ProgressBar, the guess would be you are blocking the UI with your processing and the "ghost" you are seeing is the inability of the gui to refresh the forms properly.

Answer (score 1):

You may be blocking the UI thread, try this:

```
using(FormA formA= new FormA)
{ 
    if(formA.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {

    }
}

Application.DoEvents(); //make sure the ui refreshes

FormB formB = new FormB;
formB.Show();
...{
    formB.progressBar.PerformStep();
...}
formB.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code below the code with `FormB` will be done in the Form Closed event of `FormA`, making sure `FormA` is closed before `FormB` is shown.

```
using(FormA formA= new FormA)
{ 
    formA.FormClosed += delegate(...) {
        FormB formB = new FormB;
        formB.Show();
        ...{
           formB.progressBar.PerformStep();
        ...}
        formB.Close();  
    };
    if(formA.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {

    }
}
```